# php header file transfer corrupted

Tags: php, linux, file, header, transfer

I have some files in a folder. i use the following php code to transfer the file to browser (with headers).

i download the correct length of file in .7z format but i can't unzip it.
if i transfer the same file with ftp, i can unzip it without problem.
From my server i can unzip it without problem to. so the error is somewhere in php

```
    private function pushToBrowser($file){
    if(!$file){ // file does not exist
        die('file not found');
    } else {
        header("Cache-Control: public");
        header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
        header("Content-Type: application/zip");
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
        header("Content-length: ".filesize($file).";\n");

        // read the file from disk
        readfile($file);
    }
}
```

an the usage ot the code

```
$this->pushToBrowser($path);
```

Comment: I guess that you send the wrong content-type? try to set content-type to application/x-7z-compressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before you call `readfile($path)` do a `ob_clean();` & `flush();`

so finally your code should look like:

```
private function pushToBrowser($file){
    if(!$file){ // file does not exist
        die('file not found');
    } else {
        header("Cache-Control: public");
        header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
        header("Content-Type: application/x-7z-compressed");
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
        header("Content-length: ".filesize($file).";\n");
        ob_clean();
        flush();
        // read the file from disk
        readfile($file);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> For serving 7 zip files your content type should be
>   **`application/x-7z-compressed`**

If you are serving both 7 zip & zip or rar files then you have to programmatically set the content type to the browser.